# Django Result return absolute URL's

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

So I have a fairly straightforward serializer in `serializers.py`

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FrozenSchedule
        fields = ['startDate', 'endDate', 'client', 'url']

    startDate = serializers.DateField(source='start_date')
    endDate = serializers.DateField(source='end_date')
    client = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False)
    url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url')
```

`get_absolute_url` in my `models.py`

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('reports:frozenschedule-detail', kwargs={
        'slug': self.client.slug, 'pk': self.id
    })
```

And it's related ViewSet in `viewsets.py`

```
class ScheduleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = FrozenSchedule.objects.not_abandoned().future()\
        .filter(signed=False).order_by('start_date')
    serializer_class = serializers.ScheduleSerializer
```

It returns JSON which looks like this:

```
 [
    {
        "startDate": "2016-10-01",
        "endDate": null,
        "client": "Abscissa.Com Limited",
        "url": "/clients/abscissac/frozenschedule/1",
    }
]
```

But I'd like it to return the complete URL, not just the relative path

```
[
    {
        "startDate": "2016-10-01",
        "endDate": null,
        "client": "Abscissa.Com Limited",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/clients/abscissac/frozenschedule/1",
    }
]
```

Could I serialize URL's this way inside my  Serializer?

The Restful documentation states that the rest_framework `reverse` function does exactly what I need. But it requires the request object to build the UR
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/

Comment: show us your get absolute url method from model

Comment: Can you try with `HyperlinkedIdentityField` ?

Comment: I take it I need tp specify my view name like `url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='reports:frozenschedule-detail', lookup_field={'pk': ...})` but how do I specify the lookup fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [customise this behavior of a hyperlinked field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields) by overiding `get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format)` method.
This method is used to *map the object instance to its URL representation*.
For example:

```
class UrlHyperlinkedIdentityField(HyperlinkedIdentityField):
   def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
     if obj.pk is None:
       return None

    return self.reverse(view_name,
        kwargs={
            'slug': obj.client.slug,
            'pk': obj.id,
        },
        request=request,
        format=format,
    )
```

Then in  `serializers.py` :

```
url = UrlHyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='reports:frozenschedule-detail')
```